# How can i dynamically change the logo image based on country in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have five country logo images in my App page.
Now i want to change logo dynamically based on country.
How can i replace logo?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Declare a global variable like this

BitmapImage bit;

Step 2:
choose your image uri by using switch statement:

```
public void ChoseUri(string cuntryName)
        {
            switch (cuntryName)
            {
                case "US":
                    bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image/Us.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    break;
                case "INDIA":                                 
                    bit = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image/INDIA.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    break;
               default:
            }
        }
```

Step3: Set your image source dynamically:

imgCountry.Source=bit;

Comment: set your five country uri inside this switch statement